# use direct crop feature of gallery to by providing image uri

Tags: android, image, gallery, crop

This is the code which opens gallery and pick an image to crop it. The change I need is I don't want to open the gallery to pick image. I have already image in my imageview. How can I pass uri of image with intent to use direct crop feature of gallery. what modification I need to do this in below code. Thanks!

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
// call android default gallery
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
// ******** code for crop image
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);
```

I have modified it with

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
intent.setData(edtImgUri);
```

but it is also not working.

Comment: http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

Comment: Check this pls https://github.com/biokys/cropimage

Answer (score 1):

You must add the `output` and `outputFormat` Extra's to the intent. Output should be carfeully chosen, so that it can be written by the system (gallery), and read by your app.

This is working for me :

```
    final Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");

    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");

    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);

    // We should always get back an image that is no larger than these
    // dimensions
    intent.putExtra("outputX", 128);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", 128);
    // Scale the image down to 128 x 128
    intent.putExtra("scale", true);

    intent.putExtra("windowTitle",
            profileActivity.getString(R.string.pick_picture));

    File tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "/crop_avatar.png"); 

    mSavedUri = Uri.fromFile(tempFile);

    intent.putExtra("output", mSavedUri);
    intent.putExtra("outputFormat", "PNG");
    profileActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, INTENT_PICK_PICTURE);
```